How to change the size of a Shadcn dialog component?
I have a dialog component from shadcn which contains something that is wider than the actual dialog. I have been trying to apply tailwind styles such as w-[full] to the  but that seemed to not do anything. Is there a way to change the size of the actual dialog that pops up? I will paste my code. Thanks!
Shadcn - https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/dialog
Here is a photo of my design. Design
'use client';

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CollapseCardFeatures from './_components/Cards';
import Quizmodal from './_components/QuizModal';

import {
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  DialogDescription,
  DialogFooter,
  DialogHeader,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dialog"

const Page: React.FC = () => {

  return (
    <div className='w-full h-full relative'>
      <CollapseCardFeatures />
      <section className='w-full h-full flex justify-center py-5'>
        <Dialog>
            <DialogTrigger asChild>
                <div className="group relative w-fit transition-transform duration-300 active:scale-95">
                <button className="relative z-10 rounded-lg bg-gradient-to-br from-indigo-500 to-fuchsia-500 p-0.5 duration-300 group-hover:scale-110">
                    <span className="block rounded-md bg-slate-950 px-4 py-2 font-semibold text-slate-100 duration-300 group-hover:bg-slate-950/50 group-hover:text-slate-50 group-active:bg-slate-950/80">
                    Take Quiz
                    </span>
                </button>
                <span className="pointer-events-none absolute -inset-4 z-0 transform-gpu rounded-2xl bg-gradient-to-br from-indigo-500 to-fuchsia-500 opacity-30 blur-xl transition-all duration-300 group-hover:opacity-90 group-active:opacity-50" />
                </div>
            </DialogTrigger>
            <DialogContent className="w-full">
                <Quizmodal />
            </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
        </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Page;




i tried your code it shows full screen model i think something wrong with your layout or somthing or quizmodal code

You need to overwrite max-width property
<DialogContent className="max-w-fit">
  <Quizmodal />
</DialogContent>

Note: w-full was already applied by shadcn CLI, so no need to add it manually

Thanks. In my case I need to add exclamation mark though. So className="!max-w-fit" should work.
